# laravel jquery count table row append auto increment id

Tags: jquery, laravel

how can i achieved this in my Laravel application using ajax request.
My logic is

1. on page reload table auto numbering table row
   {**example.** `td=1,td=2,td=3`}
2. upon Ajax post submitted append data + auto numbering to existing number on the table
   {**example.** `td=1,td=2,td=3,td=4`}

as you can see `td=4` is the new added value .. 
how can i achieved this and make sure when page reload the numbering maintain.

**Code:**

```
$('#myform').on( "submit", function( event ) {
  event.preventDefault(); 
  $.ajax({
    type:'POST',
    url:"{{ URL::route('test') }}",
    data:$(this).serialize(),
        success:function(data){
          console.log(data)
                        var $table = $('#myTable');
                         for (var i=0;i<1;i++) {
                               var $row = $table.find("tbody").append("<tr>"+
                                  "<td>"+i+"</td>"+
                                  "<td id='name'>"+data.name+"</td>"+
                                  "<td id='code'>"+data.code+"</td>"+
                                  "</tr>").children("tr:eq("+i+")"); 
                         } }});});
```

Comment: on page load is this `td=4` persist? I don't think so as this is added through jquery code.

Comment: How do you show the table in page load ??

Comment: i'm showing it via normal blade view , only post method is using ajax and append it, i was thinking  it is not possible since page load is a return from controller view

Comment: Do you got a solution ?

Comment: nope still aint working ..

Answer (score 0):

In your for loop you have defined `i<1` which will execute only once. So you need to run the loop based on ajax response data.

If you want to persist the numbering you can add this ajax code in a function and call that function when page loads and on form submit.

For Example :

```
function postData() {
            $.ajax({
    type:'POST',
    url:"{{ URL::route('test') }}",
    data:$(this).serialize(),
        success:function(data){
          console.log(data)
                        var $table = $('#myTable');
                         for (var i=0;i<1;i++) {
                               var $row = $table.find("tbody").append("<tr>"+
                                  "<td>"+i+"</td>"+
                                  "<td id='name'>"+data.name+"</td>"+
                                  "<td id='code'>"+data.code+"</td>"+
                                  "</tr>").children("tr:eq("+i+")"); 
                         } }});
} 


$(document).on( "ready", function() {
  postData();
)};

$('#myform').on( "submit", function( event ) {
   postData();
)};
```

Comment: the postData represent as what?

Comment: postData is just function name, you can rename it whatever you want

Comment: when page is loaded post data will be empty?  meaning the table TD=empty

Comment: you can pass post data as parameter to postData() function

Answer (score 0):

in for of you : `for (var i=0;i<1;i++)` 
You only get 1 record 
if you want more than 1 you can : `for (var i=0;i<data.length;i++)`
You want automatically add the number of table (td start 1) :

```
                         var $table = $('#myTable');
                         var increase = 1 ;
                         for (var i=0;i<data.length;i++) {
                               var $row = $table.find("tbody").append("<tr>"+
                                  "<td>"+(increase+i)+"</td>"+
                                  "<td id='name'>"+data[i].name+"</td>"+
                                  "<td id='code'>"+data[i].code+"</td>"+
                                  "</tr>").children("tr:eq("+i+")"); 
                         } }});
```